# Only desired traps should be received by snmptrapd

Tags: snmp

Is there be any mechanism around through which we can only receive desired traps.
         I mean to say suppose we only want to receive cold-start/warm start traps not Authorization-failure trap ...Can we restrict our snmptrapd to receive cold-start/warm-start trap??...Even though Authorization-failure traps also raised on the same time by the device.

Thanks in Advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no filtering mechansim to filter out specific traps from snmptrapd.  There actually is an option (`ignoreAuthFailure`) option for removing authentication failure traps, but that's the only one.

You could define a `traphandle`, though, and do your own logging within it and have it generate a log with a specific set of traps you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Wes....I will see it .........Are u able to give me any idea that how to write traphandler...I mean, ever u come across any tutorial or u have had written it by urself....I want some help regarding traphandler..Please give me any idea???

Comment: The `traptoemail` script is a traphandle that comes with net-snmp.  It's in the `local` directory of the source tree, or may have been installed in /usr/bin on your system.